# Character totally changes when in italics

Tags: html, css, character, ascii, italics

I have a small problem with the character "т", ascii code : 209 130

When this character is set in italics, the letter changes totally...

Here is the т character in italics (inspect the code it is amazing):

*т*

Do you have any idea if it is normal ?

Maybe it's part of a laguage that have different letters display in italics ?

Or if it is a bug => Who could I report this to?

Bad display visible on Firefox and Chrome, I did not test on Safari, Edge or Opera

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, the [Wikipedia page on this letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Te_(Cyrillic)) (which is from the cyrillic alphabet) mentions that it looks like this in cursive.

Comment: Well this was unexpected. I should have checked ! I will accept this answer as soon as StOw permits me.